# How to write the right URL for an image

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, path

Im making a game with JavaFX and want to load images into it. Im having trouble with finding the correct URL to load the image

Its supposed to be a Memory game and the image is supposed to be loaded into a button for the player to interact with. Normally when I tried working with images, I start the URL at the projects folder and it works fine but here I keep getting error messages. I only get it to work when I type in the full URL from the C: Drive but shouldnt it also be possible to access it just from projects folder?

This is the constructor of the class for the Memory Cards

```
public MemoryCard(String front, int picID) 
    {
        front = new ImageView(front);

        picBack = new ImageView("src/grafics/back.jpg");
        setGraphic(picBack);

        //...
    }
```

I have created a folder called 'grafics' under the source folder with the correct images inside. I thought this would work but it just gives me the IllegalArgumentException message on the line where I load the image.

Comment: Assuming `src` is marked as a resources content root then using `new Image("grafics/back.jpg")` should work. You could also do `getClass().getResource("/grafics/back.jpg").toExternalForm()` which will give you an absolute URL as a `String`. _Unrelated_: The correctly spelling is "graphics", not "grafics".

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. I already tried the suggestion you gave before and for some reason it doesnt work. I have used this URL before in a different project where the images where saved in a folder under the /src/ folder and it worked there. I dont see why /src/ shouldnt be marked as a  resources content root in this project if it is in every other. How can I check to make sure it is? _Unrelated_ Sorry for the spelling error I translated this to english before posting it here